# injecting html document into selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

im testing a website but it requires me to log in each time, so ive saved the webpage i want to test into a html document.

im trying to open it by driver.get('file:///pp.html') but as of right now it just opens the file then closes, and none of the following code works:

rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.aui  tr")
for row in rows:
    projectNames = row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[1]")
    for projectName in projectNames:
        print (projectName.text)

Answer (score 1):

In order to give it some time in order to do things there are a few ways I would approach this.

one would be to set a time load page.

```
driver = set_page_load_timeout(10)
```

maybe I would also also use the time.sleep command from the time module

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.aui tr") 
for row in rows:
    time.sleep(2) 
    projectNames = row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[1]")
        for projectName in projectNames: 
        time.sleep(1)
        print (projectName.text)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Lastly maybe if your driver is closing to quickly you should into the WebDriverWait() commmand. maybe something like this

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
row = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.xpath(".//td[1]"))
```

Hopefully this helps! good luck

Comment: hey thanks for the help! im still looking as to how to use sample.html as a driver url instead of an actual url

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, look to load your chrome_profile or a duplicate of your browser profile (whatever browser you're using) to not have to re-login after the first time.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Path\\To\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UCaZT48Nnw

Comment: oh sorry i meant to clarify that logging in meant the web site im testing not chrome itself

Comment: I know, if you use Selenium to load a profile as shown in the code, you won't have to re-login every time you try to visit the page.

Comment: do you know how to use a html file instead of a url with driver.get()?